# Disabling buttons problem on C#

Tags: c#, listbox, button

Ok so I'm trying to move items from one listbox to another by using multiple buttons i.e

I have 2 buttons cmdRight and cmdRight2 which are both disabled on form load

If the user selects a single item on the first listbox a cmdRIght button enables but cmdRight2 is still disabled , if the user selects multiple items on the first listbox a cmdRight2 button enables but cmdRight is disabled.

I've got the move buttons to work but the problem I'm having is after moving multiple items with the cmdRight2 button the cmdRight button enables (which it shouldn't it should only enable after selecting a single item in the listbox). I've tried numerous if statements etc. and yet it still happens.

I'm new to C# so any help would be appreciated.

Thank You

```
        private void lbList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.lbList1.SelectedItems != null)
            {
                cmdRight.Enabled = true; //enable cmdRight
                cmdClear.Enabled = true; //enable cmdClear
                if (this.lbList1.SelectedItems.Count > 1)//if multiple items selected
                {
                    cmdRight.Enabled = false;
                    cmdRight2.Enabled = true; //enable cmdRight2              
                }
            }
        }


    private void cmdRight2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (int i in lbList1.SelectedIndices)
        {
            lbList2.Items.Add(lbList1.Items[i].ToString());
        }
        while (lbList1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            lbList1.Items.Remove(lbList1.SelectedItems[0]);
        }
        cmdRight2.Enabled = false;

    }

    private void cmdRight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbList2.Items.Add(lbList1.SelectedItem); //Add selected item from list1 to list2
        lbList1.Items.Remove(lbList1.SelectedItem);//remove the selected item in list1

        cmdRight.Enabled = false; //disable cmdRight
    }
```

Comment: Have you put breakpoints at the start of each function to see the order that they're being called?  Or at the very least, a breakpoint each time cmdRight.Enabled is set to true.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but why not just combine the two buttons (by simply eliminating cmdRight and keeping cmdRight2)? Obviously I don't know your design, but it would probably solve your problem.

Comment: I tried the breakpoints and for some reason the if statement "if (this.lbList1.SelectedItems != null)" seems to be always true. Even when nothing is selected

Comment: Matthew: The only problem with that is it's part of an assignment I have and I have to keep the design the same which has the 2 buttons :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want

```
if (this.lbList1.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
{
}
else if(this.lbList1.SelectedItems.Count > 1)
{
}
else
{
}
```

instead of

```
if (this.lbList1.SelectedItems != null)
```

Then you could place all of this in a method called "EnableButtons" as mentioned elsewhere

Comment: Yey!!! That worked thank you soooo much!

I'll research into doing methods next. Thank you so much! Been trying to do that since last night.

Comment: When you're working through problems, and you see something like SelectedItems is never null, you'll need to find another switch (as in this case, the # of items selected)

Answer (score 3):

How about creating one method `EnableButtons` that enables/disables to buttons according to given criteria like "enable cmdRight2 only if.... is true".

Then, call the method whenever some of the criteria might change. The advantage of this over the way you're doing it now is that the criteria within the method are "absolute" (in that the buttons are either enabled or disabled in one go) instead of "relative" (enable the button when the user does this or that).

You could also call this method from the `Application.Idle` event instead of calling it in response to some user action.

**EDIT**

Declare the following method:

```
private void EnableButtons()
{
    controlX.Enabled = (<condition...>);
    controlY.Enabled = (<condition...>);
}
```

You can either invoke that method from the positions in code where something should change in the buttons' enabled states, or you can do the following in the constructor of the form:

```
public Form1()
{
    // Other code...

    Application.Idle += new <The respective event handler>;
}
```

Then, declare a method with the respective signature for the event and call `EnableButtons` there. This method would be called in situations where your application is "idle" (waiting for user actions).

Comment: I'm quite new to programming so I'm not sure how to do that... :-S

Comment: Good suggestion.  He'll still need to fix the enable/disable logic, though.

Comment: @KP: I edited my reply with some pseudo-code. You'll easily find out what I mean - I just don't have the correct syntax in mind right now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are removing the items one by one, so when only one item is left, you essentially have one item selected so your program enables the cmdRight.  The easiest way around this is to have

```
cmdRight2.Enabled = false;
cmdRight.Enabled = false;
```

at the end of the cmdRight2_Click method.